# Remove year from dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have 20 years worth of weather data, but I'm only interested in the patterns per year. I don't care how June 1995 is different from June 2011, for example. Instead, I want to have 20 values for June 1, 20 values for June 2, etc.

**My question:** How do I drop the year portion of a date object, keep the month AND day, while also maintaining the sequential properties of dates? My ultimate goal is a long list of repeated mm/dd values corresponding each to the outcome variable. I'll treat the mm/dd like factors, but in the correct order.

```
# Given this:
as.Date(c("2014-06-01","1993-06-01", "2013-06-03", "1999-01-31"), "%Y-%m-%d")
# I want to get this:
"06-01" "06-01" "06-03" "01-31"
# That will sort like this
"01-31" "06-01" "06-01" "06-03"
```

Little hacks like using sub() to drop the year and convert the dash to a decimal doesn't work because then the 1st of the month is the same as the 10th of the month. I also tried turning the dates into character strings, removing the year, and then turning it back into a date... that just made everything year 2014.

Comment: There may be some subtleties. Is the 29th Feb in a leap year before, after, or the same as the 1st March in a non-leap year? You might want to use the `yday` function from the `lubridate` package which returns the index of a day in a year. Other functions in `lubridate` may be helpful too, worth checking out.

Comment: Interesting, that might do what I need it to. If I have m/d anyway though it won't matter about leap years because 2/30 will be a distinct level.

Comment: This is why data.frames exist. You can use @jalapic's answer to make a 2-column data.frame and sort it using `dplyr::arrange()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does this work?

```
temp<-as.Date(c("2014-06-01","1993-06-01", "2013-06-03", "1999-01-31"), "%Y-%m-%d")

x<-format(temp, format="%m-%d")

 x
[1] "06-01" "06-01" "06-03" "01-31"


sort(x)
[1] "01-31" "06-01" "06-01" "06-03"
```

Comment: They no longer seem to be `date` objects, and using `as.Date` doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

jalapic's answer just before mine, transforms the date column into a *character vector* (the object passed in to *format* is returned as a character for pretty printing).

according to the OP, one reason for getting rid of the year, perhaps the key one, is to roll-up by by day & month, regardless of year. To me, that suggests a time series is not the right data type for this column, instead you are better off with an ***ordered*** ***factor*** which will preserve the "*sequential properties of dates*" as OP requires.

this is pretty much the

Granted, a factor does not understand dates or numbers, but it does understand unique values, which in this instance at least, it should behave as the OP wants

```
> d = "2014-06-01"
> d = as.Date(d)

fnx = function(x) {
         unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), '[19|20][0-9]{2}-', fixed=FALSE))[2]
     }

> dm("2012-01-25")
    [1] "01-25"

> dm1 = sapply(column_of_date_objs, fnx)

> new_col = as.factor(dm1, ordered=TRUE)
```

Comment: I too wasn't sure about 'sequential properties of dates'.   In my solution, you're right that the year is still recognized.   The sort(x) does return the mm-dd format in the order requested.  I interpreted keeping the sequential properties as maybe wanting to possibly order the vector by the date at some point.  order(x) will do that ... e.g. it returns [1] 4 1 2 3   in this example.   I like your solution also though.