# How do you delete year values only from date columns in R?

Tags: r

I am analyzing GPS data for seasonal movements of wild hogs over a multi-year period. I'm not concerned with years, just months and days. My date columns are formatted, '%m/%d/%Y' (eg. 4/12/2017). I would like to delete the %Y (all years) in the entire column so that it reads '%m/%d' (eg. 4/12). Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems all you have to do is change the `format` in `as.Date`, as answered [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966827/remove-year-from-dates-in-r).  First answer on Google, FWIW =)

Comment: One option would be to change them so they all have the same year...

Comment: I would say what you are doing is an Xy problem. You  want seasonal data, there are solutions out there much more robust thtn what you are seeking.

Comment: Use something like `gsub("(.*)/\\d{4}$","\\1",df$date)`

Comment: Language added.

Comment: with lubridate: a <- dmy("4/12/07")   ; then: paste(day(a), month(a)) = "4 12"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best optimized option would be to use `gsub` and replace `year` value as:

```
gsub("(.*)/\\d{4}$","\\1","4/12/2017")
#[1] "4/12"
```

Suppose you got a data.frame as `df` having date column as `date` then one can try:

```
df$date <- gsub("(.*)/\\d{4}$","\\1",df$date)
```