# Dividing data based on custom date range

Tags: r

I have a time series which spans multiple years and want to divide it into four categories based on date (ie, 15 April - 10 May, 11 May - 10 July, and so on). My first thought was to use `lubridate` to define each time period with `interval()` and then use `%within%` to determine whether an event occurs within it or not.

```
df
      id            datetime
1  HAR10 2019-06-26 04:35:06
2  HAR05 2019-08-05 19:15:00
3  HAR07 2018-07-26 01:01:00
4  HAR07 2018-07-24 23:36:00
5  HAR05 2019-08-27 18:59:43
6  HAR05 2019-07-12 03:33:00
7  HAR07 2018-08-09 16:21:00
8  HAR07 2019-05-01 00:04:28
9  HAR04 2019-07-01 05:25:00
10 HAR07 2018-07-18 15:17:00

perA <- interval(ymd(20190511), ymd(20190710))

df %within% perA
```

I immediately ran into a problem with year, since I want to get all events from, say, April - May, regardless of what year they occurred, but `interval` is year-specific so the interval defined above works for my 2019 data but not my 2018 data. I could define a new set of intervals for each year, but that seems very messy.

Another problem is that a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which `%within%` returns, is not what I need. I need to assign each event to a category based on which time range it falls within.

My second thought was  to use `filter()`, but I don't think that solves either of my problems. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can extract the month from the date and group by/filter based on that. `lubridate::month()`

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be month and day (ie April 15, not just April).

Comment: There's a `day` for that, too. I just removed the year and gave them all the same year. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily extract the `month`, `day` or even `hour` and set to the same year across dates. I made up some groups. This is a `dplyr` solution, but you should be able to easily convert to `base` if you prefer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(noyeardate = as.Date(paste(2000, month(datetime), day(datetime), sep = "-")), 
         interval = case_when(noyeardate %within% interval(ymd(20000101), ymd(20000331)) ~ "Group 1", 
                              noyeardate %within% interval(ymd(20000401), ymd(20000630)) ~ "Group 2", 
                              noyeardate %within% interval(ymd(20000701), ymd(20000930)) ~ "Group 3", 
                              noyeardate %within% interval(ymd(20001001), ymd(20001231)) ~ "Group 4"))

      id            datetime noyeardate interval
1  HAR10 2018-07-18 15:17:00 2000-07-18  Group 3
2  HAR05 2018-07-24 23:36:00 2000-07-24  Group 3
3  HAR07 2018-07-26 01:01:00 2000-07-26  Group 3
4  HAR07 2018-08-09 16:21:00 2000-08-09  Group 3
5  HAR05 2019-05-01 00:04:28 2000-05-01  Group 2
6  HAR05 2019-06-26 04:35:06 2000-06-26  Group 2
7  HAR07 2019-07-01 05:25:00 2000-07-01  Group 3
8  HAR07 2019-07-12 03:33:00 2000-07-12  Group 3
9  HAR04 2019-08-05 19:15:00 2000-08-05  Group 3
10 HAR07 2019-08-27 18:59:43 2000-08-27  Group 3
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("HAR10", "HAR05", "HAR07", "HAR07", "HAR05", "HAR05", "HAR07", "HAR07", "HAR04", "HAR07"), 
                 datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2018-07-18 15:17:00", "2018-07-24 23:36:00", 
                                         "2018-07-26 01:01:00", "2018-08-09 16:21:00", "2019-05-01 00:04:28", 
                                         "2019-06-26 04:35:06", "2019-07-01 05:25:00", "2019-07-12 03:33:00", 
                                         "2019-08-05 19:15:00", "2019-08-27 18:59:43")))
```

Comment: This seems to work, except I receive the message "Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied." I got around this by creating a dataframe with all my start and end dates and specifying tz when calling ymd() for the entire thing. It's messy but it seemed less messy than using tz twice in each interval(). I also have a period that spans the new year (September through April) and I had to split this into two: Sept-Dec and Jan-Apr. Is there a more elegant way to do either of these things?

Comment: @user72959 You just need to set up the dates with time zones from the start. If you don't need the time stamp with the date, it would be better to convert to date format using `as.Date`. Dates are annoying to deal with, but those of us that deal in time series have no choice. The way `case_when` works is that after it classifies everything in the case, it changes their logicals to FALSE, so you could do Jan-Apr and for the last case do `TRUE ~ "Group 1"` to add the remaining Sept-Dec dates to the same group. I guess that would be a little neater.

Comment: @user72959 Here's a question that deals with removing the year from a date and maintaining its sequential attributes. I personally don't think it's any more elegant but if you think so, give it a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966827/remove-year-from-dates-in-r