# How can I sort by date a column that only has month and day with R?

Tags: r

My data frame look a bit like this:

```
x         freq
1-Apr     892
1-Aug     1221
1-Dec     923
1-Feb     880
1-Jan     889
```

...

And I can´t seem to sort them in order

Comment: Can you give examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Have you tried with `as.Date(x, "%d-%b")` or similar?

Comment: I tried this: `df[order(df$x),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df[order(as.Date(df$x, "%d-%b")), ]
      x freq
5 1-Jan  889
4 1-Feb  880
1 1-Apr   92
2 1-Aug 1221
3 1-Dec  923
```

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  x freq
  1-Apr 92
  1-Aug 1221
  1-Dec 923
  1-Feb 880
  1-Jan 889",
  header = TRUE)
```

**Attempts**

Going off of what Alexlok's answer,

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = as.Date(df$x, format = "%d-%b"))

x           freq
2020-04-01  92          
2020-08-01  1221            
2020-12-01  923         
2020-02-01  880         
2020-01-01  889
```

However, you can see this adds in the year (e.g., 1-Jan is 2020-01-01).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966827/remove-year-from-dates-in-r) is helpful, but the format changes from date to character. However, you are able to sort by date.

```
df %>%
  mutate(x = format(as.Date(x, format = "%d-%b"), format = "%m-%d")) %>%
  arrange(x)

x       freq
01-01   889         
02-01   880         
04-01   92          
08-01   1221            
12-01   923
```