# trying to put days into weeks across different years

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have data.frames representing different years.  Each year has a date column.  I would like to create a variable in each, which groups the first 7 days of the year, the second 7 days, etc.  So "2020-01-17" would be in "01-15 to 01-21"

```
#sample Data    
x1 <- data.frame(
    day=c("2020-02-21" ,"2020-01-19" ,"2020-01-30" ,"2020-01-17" ,"2020-02-18" ,"2020-02-31", "2020-02-21" ,"2020-01-02" ,"2020-01-28", "2020-02-27" ,"2020-02-29","2020-02-11" ,"2020-01-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-10", "2020-01-31" ,"2020-02-18"),
    one = 1 )
    
    x2 <- data.frame(
    day=c("2021-02-21" ,"2021-01-19" ,"2021-01-30" ,"2021-01-17" ,"2021-02-18" ,"2021-02-31", "2021-02-21" ,"2021-01-02" ,"2021-01-28", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-29","2021-02-11" ,"2021-01-05", "2021-02-06", "2021-02-10", "2021-01-31" ,"2021-02-18"),
    one = 1 )
```

I know how to convert the days to weeks, but if I drop the year using the `format` as suggested([Remove year from dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966827/remove-year-from-dates-in-r)) it makes a character, and then I can't use `cut`.

```
x2$day <- as.Date( x2$day , "%Y-%m-%d") 
x1$day <- as.Date( x1$day , "%Y-%m-%d") 
x1$day2 <- format( x1$day , "%m-%d")
class( x1$day2)
```

If I don't drop the year, than the same date ends up in different weeks.

```
using the cut function "2020-02-21", and "2021-02-21" are in different weeks.  I want them to be in the same bin

cut(as.Date(x2$day), breaks="week")
cut(as.Date(x1$day), breaks="week")
```

Comment: Does `data.table::week(x1$day)` give the desired result? If not I may be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If this includes leap years and non leap years that won't work because the ith day of the year can fall in a different date range.  What we can do is name the groups according to the group number.  Let us number the first 14 days of the year as 0, the next 14 as 1 and so on.

```
transform(x1, g = as.POSIXlt(day, format = "%Y-%m-%d")$yday %/% 14)
```

giving:

```
          day one  g
1  2020-02-21   1  3
2  2020-01-19   1  1
3  2020-01-30   1  2
4  2020-01-17   1  1
5  2020-02-18   1  3
6  2020-02-31   1 NA
7  2020-02-21   1  3
8  2020-01-02   1  0
9  2020-01-28   1  1
10 2020-02-27   1  4
11 2020-02-29   1  4
12 2020-02-11   1  2
13 2020-01-05   1  0
14 2020-02-06   1  2
15 2020-02-10   1  2
16 2020-01-31   1  2
17 2020-02-18   1  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right path with `cut()`.
Using a weekly sequence that spans the entire year, one can use `findInterval()` to find the sequence indices (i.e week number) that matches each date.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
x1 <- data.frame(
  day=ymd(c("2020-02-21" ,"2020-01-19" ,"2020-01-30" ,"2020-01-17" ,"2020-02-18" ,"2020-02-31", "2020-02-21" ,"2020-01-02" ,"2020-01-28", "2020-02-27" ,"2020-02-29","2020-02-11" ,"2020-01-05", "2020-02-06", "2020-02-10", "2020-01-31" ,"2020-02-18")),
  one = 1 )
#> Warning: 1 failed to parse.

x2 <- data.frame(
  day=ymd(c("2021-02-21" ,"2021-01-19" ,"2021-01-30" ,"2021-01-17" ,"2021-02-18" ,"2021-02-31", "2021-02-21" ,"2021-01-02" ,"2021-01-28", "2021-02-27" ,"2021-02-29","2021-02-11" ,"2021-01-05", "2021-02-06", "2021-02-10", "2021-01-31" ,"2021-02-18")),
  one = 1 )
#> Warning: 2 failed to parse.

x1seq <- seq(dmy("01-01-2020"), dmy("31-12-2020"), by = "7 days")
x2seq <- seq(dmy("01-01-2021"), dmy("31-12-2021"), by = "7 days")
x1 %>%
  mutate(week_start = x1seq[findInterval(day, x1seq,
                                         rightmost.closed = FALSE, 
                                         left.open = FALSE, 
                                         all.inside = FALSE)])
#>           day one week_start
#> 1  2020-02-21   1 2020-02-19
#> 2  2020-01-19   1 2020-01-15
#> 3  2020-01-30   1 2020-01-29
#> 4  2020-01-17   1 2020-01-15
#> 5  2020-02-18   1 2020-02-12
#> 6        <NA>   1       <NA>
#> 7  2020-02-21   1 2020-02-19
#> 8  2020-01-02   1 2020-01-01
#> 9  2020-01-28   1 2020-01-22
#> 10 2020-02-27   1 2020-02-26
#> 11 2020-02-29   1 2020-02-26
#> 12 2020-02-11   1 2020-02-05
#> 13 2020-01-05   1 2020-01-01
#> 14 2020-02-06   1 2020-02-05
#> 15 2020-02-10   1 2020-02-05
#> 16 2020-01-31   1 2020-01-29
#> 17 2020-02-18   1 2020-02-12
x2 %>%
  mutate(week_start = x2seq[findInterval(day, x2seq,
                                         rightmost.closed = FALSE, 
                                         left.open = FALSE, 
                                         all.inside = FALSE)])
#>           day one week_start
#> 1  2021-02-21   1 2021-02-19
#> 2  2021-01-19   1 2021-01-15
#> 3  2021-01-30   1 2021-01-29
#> 4  2021-01-17   1 2021-01-15
#> 5  2021-02-18   1 2021-02-12
#> 6        <NA>   1       <NA>
#> 7  2021-02-21   1 2021-02-19
#> 8  2021-01-02   1 2021-01-01
#> 9  2021-01-28   1 2021-01-22
#> 10 2021-02-27   1 2021-02-26
#> 11       <NA>   1       <NA>
#> 12 2021-02-11   1 2021-02-05
#> 13 2021-01-05   1 2021-01-01
#> 14 2021-02-06   1 2021-02-05
#> 15 2021-02-10   1 2021-02-05
#> 16 2021-01-31   1 2021-01-29
#> 17 2021-02-18   1 2021-02-12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>